# Multidex error:- Unable to instantiate application android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication

Tags: cocos2d-x, android-studio-3.0, android-studio-2.3, android-multidex

When i run my Application on Android Studio 3.0.1 its give me this error:-

```
Unable to instantiate application android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication
```

And when i run same project with Android Studio 2.3.3, the application run.
and when i remove Multidex support in 3.0.1 like:-

**build.gradle**

```
android
{
 multiDexEnabled true
}
 dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
}
```

AndroidManifest

```
android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
```

The Application run Perfectaly
Here the Question is "How do we know my application need MulitiDex surpport or not" because in 3.0.1 its dint need.

Comment: Try to disable instant run and then run your project.

Comment: Can you please explain "How to disable instant run"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow these steps to disable Instant Run in Android Studio 3.0.1

1. Open the Settings or Preferences dialog.

   - On Windows or Linux, select File > Settings from the menu bar.
   - On Mac OSX, select Android Studio > Preferences from the menu bar.
2. Navigate to Build, Execution, Deployment > Instant Run.
3. Uncheck the box next to Enable Instant Run.